# How do I listen to store's refresh event?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Touch 2 and wonder how I listen to the Store's refresh event in my Ext.dataview.List? I want that my list automatically updates when there are new records in my store, so the refresh event seems to do the job for me, but how do I set up a listener?

Edit: Thanks to Anand Gupta I realized my problem isn't refreshing the list but just displaying it. So I will give you some more information and hope you can help me. I use NavigationView inside tabpanel. I have one list loading from localstorage which works just fine, if you tap disclose indicator you come to a form with a button "auto complete".
By tapping autocomplete the following method is called:

```
e.stopEvent();
var lastname = this.getNewUserForm().down("textfield[name=lastname]").getValue();
if(lastname!=="")
{
    var complete = this.getApplication().getController("Complete");
    this.getUserNav().push(complete.getView());
    complete.setSearch(this.getNewUserForm().down("textfield[name=firstname]").getValue(), lastname);
}
else
{
    //errormessage
}
```

The getView() method is a ref with auto create and the "setSearch" Message on Complete Controller simply loads the Store through jsonP Proxy:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("Playernames");
store.setParams({firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname});
store.load({callback: function(){
    console.log(this);
}});
```

I added a log to see that the store is properly loaded and store is properly loaded.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some more hard search I found my bug: I had a List view embedded in a Panel with an undefined layout. So I changed the layout to "fit" and it works fine.